# Cannot read property 'onRowClickHandler' of undefined

Tags: javascript, handler, react-bootstrap

I am pretty new to JS and React-Bootstrap and have read a few other questions related to this error. However, I am still unable to solve my problem. Thankful for any help you can give.

I am trying to implement a row that when clicked on will unhide another row beneath it with more detail about that row. I found this onclick handler from another question, but it was written like

```
onclickHandler = () => {}
```

which was giving me babel errors and I can't add that to my package

Here is my code simplified, didn't include the campaign objects, but just assume its a pretty simple json object

```
class Gateway extends React.Component {

  onRowClickHandler(e){
    const hiddenElement = e.currentTarget.nextSibling;
    hiddenElement.className.indexOf("collapse show") > -1 ? 
    hiddenElement.classList.remove("show") : hiddenElement.classList.add("show");
  }

   render() {
    function renderTable(element, index) {
      return (
        <tbody key={element.campaignId}>
          <tr onClick={() => this.onRowClickHandler()}>
            <td>{element.campaignId}</td>
            <td>{element.contextualSignal.value}</td>
            <td>{element.bid}</td>
            <td>{element.retrievalScore}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr className="collapse">
            <td colSpan="4">
              Demo Content1
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      )} // End of renderTable.

    return (
        <Table id="retrievalTable" striped bordered hover variant="dark">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Campaign ID</th>
              <th>Contextual Signal Value</th>
              <th>Bid</th>
              <th>Retrieval Score</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          {this.state.campaigns.map(renderTable)}
        </Table>
      </div>
    )}
}

export default Gateway
```

When I click on a row I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onRowClickHandler' of undefined
```

Comment: [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) FTW!

Comment: P.S. To provide a bit more background, rather than providing an answer to a common problem, I thought [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/) may be more appropriate! :)

Comment: Thank you very much! those are some helpful resources

Comment: No worries! Glad I could've provided some help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `this` reference is not referring to your react class but rather to the `renderTable` function, if you can move it to the class property and bind it using the react class `constructor` or to the `render` function

```
class Gateway extends React.Component {

onRowClickHandler(e){
    const hiddenElement = e.currentTarget.nextSibling;
    hiddenElement.className.indexOf("collapse show") > -1 ? hiddenElement.classList.remove("show") : hiddenElement.classList.add("show");
  }

renderTable(element, index) {
      return (
        <tbody key={element.campaignId}>
          <tr onClick={() => this.onRowClickHandler()}>
            <td>{element.campaignId}</td>
            <td>{element.contextualSignal.value}</td>
            <td>{element.bid}</td>
            <td>{element.retrievalScore}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr className="collapse">
            <td colSpan="4">
              Demo Content1
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      )
    }

render() {

return (
<Table id="retrievalTable" striped bordered hover variant="dark">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Campaign ID</th>
              <th>Contextual Signal Value</th>
              <th>Bid</th>
              <th>Retrieval Score</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          {this.state.campaigns.map((e, i) => this.renderTable.bind(this, e, i))}
        </Table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Gateway
```

something like that, don't copy and paste., you probably know the next step

Comment: Oh I see, I came from java so I always though that this referred to the class, Thank you for the explanation. Very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful about the meaning of `this` in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind `this.handlerFunction` and pass it to `onClick`, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.

This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without `()` after it, such as `onClick={this.handlerFunction}`, you should bind that method.

[Handling Events Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

There are two ways to deal with this, first is to bind the function under constructor like:

constructor(props) {
super(props);

```
// This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
this.onRowClickHandler= this.onRowClickHandler.bind(this);
```

}

or second is to create an `arrow function` like:

```
onRowClickHandler = () => {
  // your logic here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance and reference link! I wish I could give you an upvote but alas

Comment: @T.Dakin no issue brother, happy coding :)